# How to bind ContextMenu items in a nested DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have nested DataGrid. The nested Grid is displayed as RowDetails of the selected DataGrid. This is my class structure that is binded with the DataGrid

```
public class CustomTable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
            public List<DataTable> Main { get; set; }
            private List<string> _menu;
            public List<string> Menu
            {
                 get
                 {   
                     return _menu;
                 }
                 set
                 {
                     _menu = value
                     OnPropertyChanged("Menu");
                 }
            }

            private CustomTable _child;
            public CustomTable Child
            {
                get
                {
                     return _child;
                }
                set
                {
                     _child = value;
                     OnPropertyChanged("Child");
                }
            }
            public DataRowView _selectedItem;
            public DataRowView SelectedItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return _selectedItem;
                }
                set
                {
                    _selectedItem = value;
                    Child = new CustomTable();
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                }
            }  


        public CustomTable()
        {
            Main = new List<DataTable>();
            Main.Add(someRandomTable());

        }

        private DataTable someRandomTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
            return table;
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string caller)
        {

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
            }
        }

}
```

This is my XAML to to bind the datagrid with datatable. I want to bind Menu list to DataGrid. Thanks

```
<ScrollViewer>
<ScrollViewer.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:CustomTable}">
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Main}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid Name="dg" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
                            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl Margin="10"
                                                    Content="{Binding DataContext.Child, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl,AncestorLevel=2}}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ScrollViewer.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding TableCollection}"/>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What's your question? Something about a `ContextMenu`? And also please post your XAML

Comment: @JonathonLee Sorry my bad. Somehow i missed it. Yes I want to add ContextMenu to each level of DataGrid

Comment: is the property `Menu` is supposed to be the context menu of the data grid?

Comment: @pushpraj Yes. If I right Click on any row on DataGrid. It should display all the elements of Menu List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

screenshot

[image: screenshot]

xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="dg"
            SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.Menu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

note these two things

- `Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"` in data grid and
- `ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.Menu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` in context menu

this is a workaround as context menu is not a part of visual tree of data grid so cannot bind to the Menu property directly or even by using `FindAncestor` etc

sample menu generation

```
public CustomTable()
{
    Main = new List<DataTable>();
    Main.Add(someRandomTable());

    Menu = new List<string>();
    Menu.Add("Menu item 1");
    Menu.Add("Menu item 2");
    Menu.Add("Menu item 3");
    Menu.Add("Menu item 4");

}
```

Comment: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735743/mvvm-wpf-validating-datagrid-row-for-autogeneratedcolumns) Any thought? You are really good at this :)