# MVVM WPF : Validating datagrid row for autogeneratedcolumns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am creating a `DataTable` whose columns are stored in a list.

```
public class CustomColumn
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public int MinLength { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<CustomColumn> Columns { get; set; }
    public DataTable MyTable { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        InitializeCustomColumns();
        MyTable = new DataTable();

        foreach (CustomColumn column in Columns)
        {
            MyTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, typeof(string));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am binding the `DataTable` to a `DataGrid` and allowing the user to add rows in the `DataGrid`. My `DataGrid` Columns are auto generated as the Column List is initialized at run time. When the user enter some value in particular column of the row, I want to validate based on `CustomColumn` Properties -> `MinLength` (Minimum string length) & `MaxLength`(Maximum allowed string length). If the validation fails I want to show the default red border that appears in DataGrid for invalid input. I am following MVVM software architecture pattern.

**EDIT**

I attached `ColumnChanging` Listener

```
MyTable.ColumnChanging += tableColumnChanging;

private void tableColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    //I am able to validate here using my logic
    if(!isValid(e))
    {
        object badValue = e.ProposedValue;
        e.ProposedValue = "Bad Data";
        e.Row.RowError = "The column contains an error";
        e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column, "Column cannot be " + badValue);
    }
    else
    {
        ... 
    }

}
```

I am able to validate but I want to display my cell with ! mark if `isValid` returns false.

Comment: -1 Abhishek, you should know by now that this is *not* a website where you can come and say *this is what I want* and expect other users to do your work for you... *you* need to do the work and only come here to ask if you are stuck on a particular part. Therefore, I'd advise that you go and try to fulfil your requirements and if you get stuck, then you should provide [*all relevant code*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @Sheridan I know I am asking a lot of questions. But I am only asking after putting my full research into it. My current WPF App is kind of complex therefore I try to simplify the problem before asking and provide a simplified sample of my problem. Some of the things are just going over my head.

Comment: Abhishek, it is not about *asking a lot of questions*... it is about asking for code, without showing that you have made an attempt yourself. As you have now provided your relevant code, I will now remove my down vote, although your code is still not complete and will not reproduce your problem.

Comment: We have a situation here. Since `DataRow` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so setting `RowError` or any other property is not propagated to UI hence we can not execute any trigge directly. so wondering if `DataTable` is a necessity or we can make use of some other collection classes as well?

Comment: @pushpraj it is really difficult at this point to move from DataTable to some other collection :(

Answer (score 1):

Well I managed to do a workaround for the same

xaml

```
<ScrollViewer xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:CustomTable}">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <l:ErrorToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ErrorToVisibilityConverter" />
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text=" ! "
                                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                                   Foreground="Red">
                                            <TextBlock.Visibility>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ErrorToVisibilityConverter}"
                                                              Mode="OneWay">
                                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Tag.Errors"
                                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                                                    <Binding />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Visibility>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <StackPanel>
                ...
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding TableCollection}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have added a `Style` for `DataGridCell` and defined a custom `Template` with our extra element to display a `!` mark

converter class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class ErrorToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DataGridColumn column = values[0] as DataGridColumn;
            ObservableCollection<DataColumnChangeEventArgs> errors = values[1] as ObservableCollection<DataColumnChangeEventArgs>;
            DataRowView view = values[2] as DataRowView;

            DataColumnChangeEventArgs args = errors.FirstOrDefault(e => (e.Row == view.Row) && (e.Column.Ordinal == column.DisplayIndex));

            return view.Row.HasErrors && args != null ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

this will detect if the current cell is the one which is affected and return the `Visibility.Visible` if true otherwise `Visibility.Collapsed` hence hiding or showing the extra element depending on the error state

change in the `CustomTable`

```
public CustomTable()
{
    ...

    Errors = new ObservableCollection<DataColumnChangeEventArgs>();
}

private void tableColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isValid(e))
    {
        object badValue = e.ProposedValue;
        e.ProposedValue = "Bad Data";
        e.Row.RowError = "The column contains an error";
        e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column, "Column cannot be " + badValue);
        Errors.Add(e);
        OnPropertyChanged("Errors");
    }
    else
    {
        DataColumnChangeEventArgs args = Errors.FirstOrDefault(ee => (ee.Row == e.Row) && (ee.Column == e.Column));
        if (args != null)
        {
            Errors.Remove(args);
            OnPropertyChanged("Errors");
        }
        //... 
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<DataColumnChangeEventArgs> Errors { get; set; }
```

result

[image: result]

so the whole idea is to add an extra property with notification change capability and use it as a trigger and other property for detecting the appropriate column, and rest is the visibility of our extra ! element in the custom template